# How to include a HTML file inside a markdown file in jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have a jekyll site with filestructure like so:

```
▾ _includes/
    post-entry.html
▾ _posts/
    2012-11-25-first-post.markdown
index.markdown
```

In my index.markdown, I want to include a `post-entry.html` like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
* {% include post-entry.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this appears as a HTML code snippet in the blog. How can i prevent the HTML from being
protected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use liquid tags in any markdown file so long as it has YAML header matter.  For instance, check out the [index.md](https://raw.github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/master/index.md) given in the [jekyllbootstrap template for Jekyll sites](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap).

If you link to your actual index.markdown or your repository itself (e.g. if it's on github), we could probably get a better idea of what has gone wrong.  Your example should work, though you might need to use HTML list element `<li>` rather than the markdown `*`.

Comment: In the file, I had to actually put the code as i mention in top, but I ended up doing as it is now. 
PS: Dont see the history, it's actually the history of a different repository. Have to do a `rebase` or something.

Comment: Cool, so it sounds like everything is working with the liquid code in the `index.markdown` file as you intended now, yes?

Comment: No. Now i'm doing the method that's actually mentioned in the bottom of your link: [like this](git://gist.github.com/4174354.git). When I include it as `{% include post.html %}`, I get an output like [so](http://imgur.com/FOoDo).

Comment: This should be the answer. Using plenty of liquid, including `include` tags, on the Jekyll project I'm working on right now.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the parser views the HTML as code blocks. The best way would be to turn off code blocks like I [asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521599/can-i-turn-off-code-blocks-in-kramdown)

To work around use the replace tag:

```
{% capture includeGuts %}
{% include post-entry.html %} 
{% endcapture %}
{{ includeGuts | replace: '    ', ''}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ post.content }}` instead.

Here's the code I use on my website as an example:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        <h2>{{ post.title }} &mdash; {{ post.date | date_to_string }}</h2>
    </a>
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -8):

You can't. Markdown files are just text files with styling. If you want to use the Liquid tags you will have to do so in your _layouts

If I am guessing right you want this markdown file on your index page? So in the default.html layout after the {{ content }} tags you could then use the liquid tags you want to use. There is no need to mix the markdown files with code.

Comment: I was relaxing on my beanbag and staring at the ceiling when it hit me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is simply wrong.  You can indeed use liquid in an index.markdown file, as I indicate in my answer.