# Can I turn off code blocks in Kramdown?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

Can I turn off code blocks in Jekyll? It would make my .md files more readable.

I have this problem for inline HTML and also for includes.

I use Jekyll to create websites and never want code blocks. Right now I'm putting styling inside of HTML like this:

```
<div class="coolclass" markdown = 1>
  <div class="anotherClass">stuff </div>

  I **love** markdown
</div>
```

The `<div class="anotherClass">stuff </div>` gets interpreted as a code block unless I remove the indenting.

```
<div class="coolclass" markdown = 1>
<div class="anotherClass">stuff </div>

  I **love** markdown
</div>
```

I'd like to just turn off code blocks since I won't ever be displaying code.

If kramdown has that option I think jekyll can set it in config like this:

```
kramdown:
 auto_id_stripping: true
 enable_coderay: false
```

I tried enable_coderay false by reading the kramdown [docs](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html), but that didn't do it.

Comment: In Rails I've added a `MyKramdown` class to `Kramdown::Parser::Kramdown` where I've deleted Kramdown's `:codeblock` parser. I have no idea how to do this in Jekyll though.

Answer (score 0):

Coderay is used only for syntax highlighting and it's already set to false in Jekyll (see Default Configuration here http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

I guess what you need is `remove_block_html_tags` in Kramdown. But it's currently not supported by Jekyll. May be you can try to install Kramdown as a separate gem to include this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I think `remove_block_html_tags` will be too [aggressive](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/remove_html_tags.html) to be useful. Maybe I just need to buck up and submit my own patch...

Answer (score 0):

Using two spaces instead of 4 spaces or a tab fixes most of the issues. However things like 'h1' ('#title') need to be at the beginning of a line to work. Not quite there yet...

#### For including html in markdown files

I'm doing this:

```
{% capture includeGuts %}
{% include signup-guts.html %} 
{% endcapture %}
{{ includeGuts | replace: '    ', ''}}
```