# Jekyll: Include HTML partial inside Markdown file

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, partial

Is there a way to include an HTML partial from a Markdown file with Jekyll?

Example:

File `index.md`:

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
---

This is a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) file.

{% include foobar.html %}
```

File `_includes/foobar.html`:

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

This unfortunately does not seem to work in my case.

For completeness, here is the entire content of my `_config.yml` file:

```
encoding: utf-8
markdown: kramdown
baseurl:
```

Comment: No problemo. Just do it !

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :) The `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags appear as plain text while the rest appears as code since it's indented with four spaces.

Comment: I updated my question to include the content of my `_config.yml` file.

Comment: Actually, you were right: raw HTML in Markdown files just work. I had other issues. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then maybe you can approve my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand your answer. You suggest to unindent my list, but it wasn't indented in the first place. Since that wasn't the problem, I don't think it's a good idea to mark it as the actual answer to my question. What about changing your answer to "No problemo. Just do it!" and then I'll accept it, since that was absolutely the correct answer :)

Comment: That was a comment not an answer. The fact that you `ul` was indented four spaces was the problem.  In markdown `line break + four space = pre>code` that's how I reproduced it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69245/discussion-between-francois-beaune-and-david-jacquel).

Answer (score 38):

A common reason the html shows up as plain text is when the html snippet is indented with at least four spaces.

This causes jekyll to interpret the html as a code block that is to be displayed literally.

(I know this was already mentioned in the comments, but it took me a while to find and understand that I had the exact same problem)

Comment: I was going nuts trying to understand why the html were being rendered as if inside backticks until I saw your answer, thanks!!!!

Comment: How can you escape this behavior?

Comment: @DickeySingh You can replace 2 spaces with 1 tab. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25755861/3793161

Comment: @Johan Gorter Several years later, you saved my soul from going insane. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

If the `.md` file you mentioned is located in `_posts` and the layout type is `post`, you can use markdown="0" or "1" to set related part as Markdown or HTML as you like because you configurated markdown to `kramdown`. Try following code:

```
---
layout: post
title: Home
---

# Markdown part

This is a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) file.

<section id="categories" markdown="1">

A list of categories:

- foo
- bar

</section>

<div id="html" markdown="0">
<h1>HTML part</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

If the `.md` file you mentioned is located in `_includes`, `_layouts` or `page`, you can directly use your code or change the layout type to `page`:

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
---

This is a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) file.

{% include foobar.html %}
```

See an example here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/master/index.md.

Just enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! I was also able to find the docs here: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks